# call buttons function on enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm trying to submit a dialog form when the user presses enter.  I had the form setup as below:

```
$("#band-dialog-form").dialog({
        buttons : {
            "Save" : function(){
                        $(this).dialog("close");
            $("#editBandForm").submit();
                            },
            Cancel : function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        },
        close : function() {

        }
    });
```

When I added the key listener I changed to:

```
                "Save" : function submitBand(){
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                $("#editBandForm").submit();
                                },
```

But my key listener can't find the function submitBand.  If I try and pull the function out of the dialog and make it:

```
"Save" : submitBand(),
```

The submitBand function is called on initialization and the page is sent without the user doing anything.  What is the propper way to used named functions in the buttons object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assigning the result of executing `submitBand` to the "Save" key, as the parentheses following `submitBand` (or "function call" construct) means "execute this function object and return the result". Try passing the function object *without* the function invocation construct:

```
"Save" : submitBand,
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do:

```
var  submitBand = function(){
           $("#band-dialog-form").dialog("close");
           $("#editBandForm").submit();
      };
```

and thenn pass a reference to the function to the button:

```
$("#band-dialog-form").dialog({
        buttons : {
            "Save" :submitBand ,
            "Cancel" : function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        },
        close : function() {

        }
    });
```